# SQL Server Max Pool Size reached (no apparent connection leak)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-6.0

We have SQL Server 2016 in our infrastructure with several APIs and windows services connected to it. All of a sudden we started getting this exception.

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
> connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
> connections were in use and max pool size was reached

All of our APIs are load balanced behind nginx. There are 3 instances of APIs running on 3 different VMs. One of the APIs which is receiving most of the traffic is getting that error.

```
SELECT SDEC.client_net_address,COUNT(*) FROM sys.[dm_exec_connections]
SDEC CROSS APPLY sys.[dm_exec_sql_text](SDEC.[most_recent_sql_handle])
AS DEST where DEST.objectid=1799013490 GROUP BY
SDEC.client_net_address order by COUNT(*) desc
```

I use this query to determine number of connections per VM

```
SELECT DEST.text,COUNT(*) FROM sys.[dm_exec_connections] SDEC CROSS
APPLY sys.[dm_exec_sql_text](SDEC.[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS DEST
--where DEST.objectid=1058102810 GROUP BY DEST.text order by COUNT(*) DESC
```

and this to determine queries that have most number of connections open.

There's always one specific stored procedure call on top having tens of thousands of connections open, out of which almost all are `SLEEPING / AWAITING COMMAND`. One after that has few hundreds, so there's massive difference in number of connections between first and second query in terms of number of connections. That query, which's in top (and has 10s of thousands of connections) is a query that gets executed 100-700 times a second depending on the load, its a basic select query with with a single inner join (Indexes are optimized for it, it never goes to key lookup nor index scan). This is not the most executed query in my application thought, there are queries which get executed 500-1000 times a second, but they do not appear in above query at all.

I use basic ADO.NET connected architecture to communicate with DB, with all the using's and `Close()` call in place. I have max pool size of 10k per instance so at peak, number of connections go as high as 30k (+ some more from other applications) this is the max I can set as setting any more would cause number of connections to reach max limit which is (as far as I know) 32k. At this point, after raising the max pool size to 10k, it got a bit stable but occasionally (once per few days) APIs still throw that error and I just restart the one that is throwing the error and all is good for next few days. There's no pattern to this happening as it has happened in mornings when the traffic is way low and at evenings when traffic is high. throughout the day number of connections oscillate between 1.5 - 9.9k. When connections go up to 9.9k, in 1-2% of cases that API starts throwing the error and needs to be restarted, in other cases APIs will hold those connections and decrease over time (few hours on average). One more weird thing is that, at the peak when all 3 instances have 9.9K connections open to DB, if I shutdown 2 instances and have just one running, It won't start throwing the error, it will work just fine even for hours.

Now regarding the query, As I saied it a simple one

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col3
WHERE t1.col1 = @param1 AND t1.col2 = 1
```

It's never executed within a transaction scope, nor the connection is ever attached to and SQL transaction, It always executes alone. We use our extensions methods and base classes for getting connections and executing queries but for this specific query I copied Microsoft own sample code to try and see if I had something wrong with mine, but that did not help either. I don't think we have a connection leak, upon searching this exception, 99% of answers are that either you must be missing a `using` statement or a `finally` block (if you are using `try catch` rather than `using` to close / dispose connections) none of which should be a problem with me as I've tried MS sample code with all the configurations possible, everything in `using`, calling `Close()` before `using`'s ending brace, etc. Nothing helps. One thing that might be correlated to all this is that we just migrated our code from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET 6 (but nothing changed regarding DB connection / calls) and after deploying it to production, this exception started occurring few weeks after.

Here are few more things that I tried:

- `NOLOCK` on both tables
- Moving tables to memory
- Restarting the database server

Comment: Please show actual C# code that you use for this procedure. Are you using MARS (doing a second query while the first is still running)? `NOLOCK` isn't going to help you for this, and is generally a bad idea

Comment: [`SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection), [`SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand) and [`SqlDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader) are all `IDisposable` and should be used in `using` blocks - or solidly protected with `try/finally` blocks that Close and Dispose them. In code reviews I've done people are pretty good at handling SqlConnection and SqlCommand, but completely forget about SqlDataReader.

Comment: _NOLOCK on both tables_ Nope - don't even start down this path. It is generally not a "solution" to any problem. Nor does that have any effect on acquiring a connection - which is a client-based operation.

Comment: There's no need to paste the sample code here as I tried all the options, I tried with everything in using, only connection in using, excplicit close calls e.t.c. I've tried to copy sample code from ms examples, basically I think I've tried everything I could come up with (more than 50 combinations), but all exibit some kind of connection pooling issues.

Comment: What I discovered so far is that the same code when put it fresh console app just opens up 10 connections and no matter how many times I execute the query, that number does not go up. I'm calling using parallel for (million calls at a time) using intel 9700k so 10 connections somehow makes sense. Same code when executed from asp opens way more connections, sometimes ranging fro few hunder all the way up to 2,000.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples, for troubleshotting I useed samples from here, and tried different combinations as mentioned, putting every disposable class in using block, adding excplicit close calls etc

Comment: Which framework are you used? We now have same problem after update from .NET6 to .NET8 ((

The same code works fine in .NET6 and have this exception like yours in .NET8

Comment: @Duskone39 This problem started after we migrated from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET 6. We never got to solve it as it solved itself; months went into research and troubleshooting, and I suddenly realized that this exception has not occurred lately. Started checking connections and it never went above 1,000. I do not know whether it was some kind of adaptation thing, or there was some network infrastructure update in our data center that might have changed something, or what it was, but it does not occur anymore